# Finding map items that have a value that matches an array of string?

Tags: go

I have my code working but I am sure that it is not optimal.

I am building a Map[string]string that contains my alarm names as keys and instanceids as values. I have an array that has just instanceids in it. I need to remove any keys from the map that have values that match the instanceids in the array. Then return a []string of alarm names. My code is working but thought that it would be good to see if I did this remotely correct. The []string in the return is optional I could probably just use the map.

Thanks for the input.

```
func CheckAlarms(alarmMap map[string]string, instances []string) (result []string)  {

    var AlarmList []string

    for _, inst := range instances{

        for k, v := range alarmMap{

            if v == inst{
                log.Printf("**** Match Found add alarm to delete list %s\n", k)
                delete(alarmMap, k)
            }
        }

    }

    for k, v := range alarmMap{
        var inst []string


        AlarmList = append(AlarmList, k)
        inst = append(inst, v)

    }

    log.Printf("end of function list length %d", len(AlarmList))
return AlarmList
}
```

Comment: Are you also doing lookups by alarm name from the same map?

Comment: No the last section is where I am building my results []string I am only deleting items from the map by alarm name. I have to use the alarm name in another function to perform operations.

Comment: If you're only doing lookups from this map by its values and not its keys, then its backwards. The key should be what you're looking up with, that's the purpose of a map.

Comment: I might have five alarm names that all have the same instanceid in the values section. I could not use the instanceid as the key. Maybe I needed a different data structure.

Comment: I would say so. Perhaps a map of instance IDs to a slice of alarms for each.

Comment: Ok that sounds interesting. I will have to look into that. Thanks